# Laravel route() function doesn't pass the right type to the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

The blade code:

```
<td><a href="{{ route('employee.show', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'employee' => $employee->id]) }}">{{ $employee->first_name }} {{ $employee->last_name }}</a></td>
                                <td><a href="{{ route('employee.update', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'employee' => $employee->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('app-text.indexEdit') }}</a></td>
                                <td><form action="{{ route('employee.delete', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'employee' => $employee->id]) }}" method="post">
```

The controller function:

```
public function edit(Employee $employee)
{
    $companies = Company::get();
    return view('employee.edit', compact('employee', 'companies'));
}
```

The error:

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\EmployeesController::edit() must be an instance of App\Employee, string given
http://localhost:8000/fr/employee/edit/1
```

The routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{lang}'], function() {

    Route::prefix('employee')->name('employee.')->group(function() {
        
        Route::get('/edit/{employee}', 'EmployeesController@edit')->name('edit');
        Route::patch('/edit/{employee}', 'EmployeesController@update')->name('update');
```

I'm trying to make the application a multi-language application so just after I added the lang variable the route won't pass the $employee->id variable. Should I add a variable that's passable to my controller for the lang variable?
any solution? Many thanks.

Comment: Seems like, the route `employee.show` accept 1 parameter but you are passing 2 parameter.

Comment: Yeah, should i just add that parameter to the controller?

Comment: You can try change your function to `public function edit(Request $request)` tell me if you get an another error

Comment: Can you include your route definition?

Comment: I just included it above.

Comment: We can, it works with other links. The problem is within the array that I'm passing to the controller it, maybe, changes the type of the **$employee->id** to a string or another thing that I can't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can make a route to change language

```
Route:: get('lang/{lang}', function ($locale) {
    session(['locale' => $locale]);
    return \Redirect::back();
})
```

step 2: middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::setLocale(session('locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }
```

after you can make a group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'language'],function(){
    //routes with u want change language
    Route::get('/edit/{employee}', 'EmployeesController@edit')->name('edit');
    Route::patch('/edit/{employee}', 'EmployeesController@update')->name('update');
});
```

and you forget to send the language in each route

Comment: I forgot it after make you can use
**@if(Session('locale') == 'en')** or es or another acronym, in all blade into group language

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are wrong. As the stack trace says the controller method is expecting an instance of your `Employee` model but you are passing in a string

Change

```
public function edit(Employee $employee)
```

To

```
public function edit(Request $request, $employeeId) // you can remove $request if you dont intend to perform redirects
```

So in the end your code looks like

```
public function edit(Request $request, $employeeId)
{
  $employee = Employee::find($employeeId);
  $companies = Company::all(); // use all instead of get if you arent going to perform selections.
  return view('employee.edit', compact('employee', 'companies'));
}
```

Note: you may need to handle cases where employee is not found based on the `$employeeId` supplied

Comment: I did your solution but it gave me another error I don't think that **$employee** is different from **Employee $employee** .
The error:
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: /home/ali/Administration/resources/views/employee/edit.blade.php)

Comment: @Ali well the id is not being found `dd()`  the `$employee` variable and see what you get. also you may need to reconfigure your routes,

Comment: modify your routes as per @Tanvir Ahmed soultion

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify your routes like these

**in web.php**

```
Route::get('your-route/{lang}/{id}','YourController@edit');
```

**In your controller**

```
public function edit($lang,Employee $employee)
{
    $companies = Company::get();
    return view('employee.edit', compact('employee', 'companies'));
}
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem comes from the blade view, not the controller. When I added that lang variable to the array 

<td><a href="{{ route('employee.update', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'employee' => $employee->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('app-text.indexEdit') }}</a></td>

It started to give the error when I remove it the error is gone but the multi-language thing is also gone.

Comment: ok let me clear one thing first why you need to pass getLocale()???.....if you call it in your controller then you can also get the same result

Comment: and after using my code what error you got can you show me???

Comment: Same error in my question. How would you call it from the controller when you want to change the language by a nav link?

Comment: so with these buttons you are changing the languages???am i right??

Comment: Yes, and the blade code for that is:

<li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'en') }}" class="nav-link">En</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'fr') }}" class="nav-link">FR</a>
                        </li>

That 'en' and 'fr' are the arguments passed to the {lang} variable in the route

Comment: href="{{ route('employee.update', ['lang' => app()->getLocale(), 'employee' => $employee->id]) }}"

The 'lang' here is the string that is being passed to the edit function but I want to pass the 'employee'

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing `locale` as well in the route then it should be as below:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('your-Own-route/{lang}/{employee}','YourController@edit');
```

**Controller edit method**

```
public function edit($lang,Employee $employee)
{
    $companies = Company::get();
    return view('employee.edit', compact('employee', 'companies'));
}
```

Comment: I included my routes above, have a look and tell me is it different?

Comment: you can't add locale prefix in the group. i also did it in one of my project and it didn't work so i added the locale parameter in each route which was the only solution